Check img filetype in Tampermonkey
I wanna check if certain images are gifs. However, the image URL used in the src of the img tag don't have the file ending in the URL. Thus it's not possible to know if the image is a gif by the source URL.
I tried to fetch the image as a blob, as described here: HtmlImageElement - how to get image type if its src doesn't have extension
But Tampermonkey didn't recognize fetch as a function.
Is there another way to check the images filetype?

fetch is a built-in function, it's not a part of Tampermonkey, so you may be using it incorrectly, but anyway the image may be cross-origin so you should use GM_xmlhttpRequest({url: '...', method:'HEAD', onload: check}) and in check function you'll check responseHeaders for content-type.

If it’s practical/convenient to create a small hidden window and load the image url, you can then...
let ImageType = Window_Id.contentWindow.document.contentType;

The returned value should be in the form "image/gif" etc.
